# Is this correct: "一个游戏有四个季度"

Tags: translation

I wanted to find out how to say a sports game has four quarters and the translation I received from Google was: "一个游戏有四个季度"

Certain sports games are split into 4 quarters rather than 2 halves and I want to express this, but I was interested in seeing "季度" used to mean quarter.

When I check Wiktionary there is no entry for 季度 but 季 says it is used to mean a quarter of a year or season.

Can 季度 also be used for other things that come in quarters?

Comment: I will put in this word into WT now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

A quarter in a sports game is usually translated as 节. For example, fourth quarter is 第四节. The first and second quarters are collectively referred to as 上半场 and similarly, the third and fourth quarters are referred to as 下半场. A sports season is usually translated as 赛季．

季度, when tranlated into English, only refers to a quarter of a year, as you have noted.

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to say "a game has four quarters" is:

> 一场比赛有四节

In terms of sports game, "game" should be translated to "比赛" rather than "游戏". "季度" is very different from the meaning you want to express. As James has explained, it only refers to a quarter of a year.

Answer (score 2):

季度 means quarter of a year 
四个季 means 4(quantity) quarters

in context

一个游戏有四个季度 Means "1 game has 4 quarters of a year"

游戏有四个季 Means "The game has 4 quarters"

一个游戏有四个季 Means "1/a game has 4 quarters"

Note: I'm a non-native speaker - if you can get a response from a native speaker I would be going with that

Comment: Another issue here is, Scott, that a (sports) game is completely different in Chinese to a game as in a usually non-competitive pursuit or activity for the sake of entertainment such as a computer game or a card game. So 游戏 here is not appropriate at all. (一场)比赛 would be the correct term.

Comment: Thanks James, I do appreciate the feed back. I'm still trying to learn Chinese so feed back is great.

Answer (score 1):

**quarter** can be translated into a lot of different meanings in Chinese

1) n. 四分之一； (25%)

2) n. 地区； Residential Quarter

3) n. 季度；For quarters of a year

4) n. 一刻钟；(15 minutes)

5) n. 两角五分；(0.25 CNY)

6) n. 节 (Sports, like basketball)

Comment: 15 minutes, you mean

Answer (score 0):

季度 = season.

游戏 means a small game such as a video game, or a computer game. It is quite common that Chinese use 比赛/体育比赛 to describe a sports game.

e.g. 
basketball games, 篮球比赛/篮球赛
football games， 足球比赛/足球赛
for short 球赛

Therefore, a common expression of your meaning is
一场比赛有四节。

Answer (score -2):

I think the 季度 would be 制度（with the meaning of particular institution or system).

The meaning of sentence is "There are four rules in a game."

Comment: This is not what the question is asking.